# How to store a particular node from an output of a state.sls file in a variable for SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I'm working on a project where I need to check the status of a service, let's call it RunningService on multiple(more than 500 machines) Windows servers. We are using Saltstack extensively for our deployments.
I'm able to check the status of my service using the below code

```
status_ser:
  module.run:
    - name: service.status
    - m_name: RunningService
```

The response that I'm getting on running via this particular code is as below:

```
----------
          ID: status_ser
    Function: module.run
        Name: service.status
      **Result: True**
     Comment: Module function service.status executed
     Started: 16:20:58.295237
    Duration: 78.124 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              ret:
                  True

Summary for minion-3
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:  78.124 ms
```

However, I only want the result part(which could be **True** or **False**) out of this in a bigger code probably saved in a variable. And then I'll verify

```
if var == 'False'
  then start RunningService
else
  do nothing
endif
```

How can I get only the result of the service as True or False?
Or a more generic question would be how to store one part of the output as variable or input to something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the output of a command or salt module as variable (the short answer) is that you use `set` in a Jinja expression. Like:

```
{% set service_status = salt['service.status']('RunningService') %}
```

Either `True` or `False` will now be stored in `service_status`. This can be used in conditional statements. Start service taking example from your question:

```
{% if not service_status %}
start_service:
  module.run:
    - service.start:
        - name: RunningService
{% endif %}
```

However, there are few things to consider:

1. All [Jinja](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3003/topics/jinja/index.html) expression is evaluated before the States are run
2. Saltstack can be better used to define the state of service, i.e. if you want a particular service to be running, just define it so.

So, its better to use the Salt state [service](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/3003/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html), which does such checks internally. Then this is all the code you'll need.

```yaml
start_service:
  service.running:
    - name: RunningService
```

Now, whenever you run this state. The service will be started if its not running, and nothing will be done if its already running.